# Merging tables and changing values simultaneously in R

Tags: r, rbind

I have a complex coding problem, I hope you can help:

Every month I have to make changes to a Lookup Table using a Changes Table that outlines (1) new Products to be added and (2) changes to Product Names. I'm trying to automate this process because I'm handling over 40,000 rows of data. There's too much sensitive data to show here, but I've given a small example of the data and the process below:

**Lookup Table**

```
dput(LookupFile)
structure(list(ProductTag = structure(c(1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 
4L), .Label = c("Confect", "Orange", "Pastries", "Root", "Sauces", 
"Spread", "White"), class = "factor"), Brand = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    BrandID = c(340, 340, 340, 400, 400, 402, 403), Name = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Cakes", "Carrots", "Choc", 
    "Honey", "Onions", "Potatoes", "Syrups"), class = "factor"), 
    NameID = c(200, 700, 100, 300, 1000, 1200, 1700)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

**Changes Table**

```
dput(ChangesFiles)
structure(list(ProductTag = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Breads", 
"Confect", "Flours"), class = "factor"), Brand = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "D"), class = "factor"), BrandID = c(340, 
403, 340), Name = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Chocolate", 
"Gluten", "Staple"), class = "factor"), NameID = c(4000, 3400, 
200)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I know `rbind` allows me to append the new data onto the Lookup Table:

```
rbind(LookupFile,ChangesFiles)
```

However there's an added layer of having to make modifications to existing rows (i.e. the product Name). In the example I've given, I want to change the following record using the ChangesFiles record, which replaces Name = 'Choc' with 'Chocolate':

`<ProductTag = 'Confect', Brand = 'A', BrandID = '340', Name = 'Choc', NameID = '200'`

This is a small data sample, so I could easily make this change manually. However, how would I make the changes on a large-scale?

I'd want it to look like this:

```
     ProductTag Brand BrandID   Name   NameID
1     Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
2      Spread     A     340     Honey    700
3    Pastries     A     340     Cakes    100
4      Sauces     B     400    Syrups    300
5      Orange     B     400   Carrots   1000
6       White     C     402    Onions   1200
7        Root     D     403  Potatoes   1700
8      Breads     A     340    Gluten   4000
9      Flours     D     403    Staple   3400
```

Answer (score 4):

From `LookupFile` take only those rows which are not defined in `ChangesFiles` and from `ChangesFiles` take everything.

```
key <- c("BrandID", "NameID") #Assuming that BrandID and NameID need to be unique
rbind(LookupFile[!interaction(LookupFile[key]) %in% interaction(ChangesFiles[key]),], ChangesFiles)

   ProductTag Brand BrandID      Name NameID
2      Spread     A     340     Honey    700
3    Pastries     A     340     Cakes    100
4      Sauces     B     400    Syrups    300
5      Orange     B     400   Carrots   1000
6       White     C     402    Onions   1200
7        Root     D     403  Potatoes   1700
1      Breads     A     340    Gluten   4000
21     Flours     D     403    Staple   3400
31    Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
```

In case you have also something to delete and you mark this with an NA in ChangesFiles you can use:

```
rbind(LookupFile[!interaction(LookupFile[key]) %in% interaction(ChangesFiles[key]),], ChangesFiles[complete.cases(ChangesFiles),])
```

Another option would be to `rbind` both tables and then use `duplicated` to remove the duplicate lines.

```
x <- rbind(ChangesFiles, LookupFile)
x[!duplicated(x[c("BrandID", "NameID")]),]
#   ProductTag Brand BrandID      Name NameID
#1      Breads     A     340    Gluten   4000
#2      Flours     D     403    Staple   3400
#3     Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
#5      Spread     A     340     Honey    700
#6    Pastries     A     340     Cakes    100
#7      Sauces     B     400    Syrups    300
#8      Orange     B     400   Carrots   1000
#9       White     C     402    Onions   1200
#10       Root     D     403  Potatoes   1700
```

Answer (score 3):

Working with your data (and just renaming them into `Changes` & `Lookup`) in `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  anti_join(Changes, Lookup,  by = colnames(Changes)),   # data  without changes
  anti_join(Lookup,  Changes, by = colnames(Lookup)[-4]) # changed names & added
  ) %>%
  arrange(BrandID, NameID)

#   ProductTag Brand BrandID      Name NameID
# 1   Pastries     A     340     Cakes    100
# 2    Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
# 3     Breads     A     340    Gluten   4000
# 4     Spread     A     340     Honey    700
# 5     Orange     B     400   Carrots   1000
# 6     Sauces     B     400    Syrups    300
# 7      White     C     402    Onions   1200
# 8       Root     D     403  Potatoes   1700
# 9     Flours     D     403    Staple   3400
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `Vlookup` option

```
> library(qdapTools)
> LookupFile$Name <- as.character(LookupFile$Name) # just for not dealing with factors
> replace <- as.character(LookupFile$ProductTag %l% ChangesFiles[,c(1,4)])  # here's a Vlookup
> ind <- !is.na(replace) # identifying value to replace
> LookupFile$Name[ind] <- replace[ind] # replacing
> rbind(LookupFile,ChangesFiles) # delivering your desired output
   ProductTag Brand BrandID      Name NameID
1     Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
2      Spread     A     340     Honey    700
3    Pastries     A     340     Cakes    100
4      Sauces     B     400    Syrups    300
5      Orange     B     400   Carrots   1000
6       White     C     402    Onions   1200
7        Root     D     403  Potatoes   1700
8      Breads     A     340    Gluten   4000
9      Flours     D     403    Staple   3400
10    Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` to the rescue! It's a one-liner..

Use an update join to update the name-column only.

```
library( data.table )
setDT(LookupFile)[ setDT(ChangesFiles), Name := i.Name, on = .(ProductTag, Brand, BrandID)][]

#    ProductTag Brand BrandID      Name NameID
# 1:    Confect     A     340 Chocolate    200
# 2:     Spread     A     340     Honey    700
# 3:   Pastries     A     340     Cakes    100
# 4:     Sauces     B     400    Syrups    300
# 5:     Orange     B     400   Carrots   1000
# 6:      White     C     402    Onions   1200
# 7:       Root     D     403  Potatoes   1700
```

`setDT()` is used to convert your data.frames to data.table-class. If your data is already in`data.table`- class,

```
LookupFile[ ChangesFiles, Name := i.Name, on = .(ProductTag, Brand, BrandID)][]
```

will also work.